# Home screen button disable not working in Google Nexus S with 4.1.2

Tags: android

I am developing an application in which HOME SCREEN button needs to be disabled. But its not working in my Nexus S with Android 4.1.2.

Below is the code i am using to disable home screen button

```
@Override 
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
 this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
 super.onAttachedToWindow(); 
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about disabling the actual device 'Home' button is not working?

Comment: Please don't disable the home button. Improving the usability of Android Apps will benefit all Android devs. Google also frowns upon this. http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/core.html

Comment: @codeMagic: Yes disabling the actual device 'Home button'

Comment: @SkyKelsey: i wan to disable it as it is a client requirement, or i want to redefine the home button activity. Anyone will do.

Comment: In that case, my comment would be the same as Sky Kelsey. I just wasn't sure if that's what you were asking.